# How can I convince Spring Boot to consider values from application.properties in my configuration class?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, configurationproperties

I have implemented a configuration class in Kotlin to read values from `application.properties` to have configurable values in the Spring Boot 2.2.2-RELEASE application.

```
package com.foo.bar.configuration

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.foo.bar.data.xyzmanagement")
class XyzManagementConfig {
    var pAssignment: PAssignment = PAssignment()

    var tAssignment: TAssignment = TAssignment()

    class PAssignment {
        var duration: Long = 10L
    }

    class TAssignment {
        var duration: Long = 10L
    }
}
```

In my application.properties I have amongst others:

```
# Configurable default values
com.foo.bar.data.xyzmanagement.pAssignment.duration=15
com.foo.bar.data.xyzmanagement.tAssignment.duration=15
```

I already have tried to annotate the main class with

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(
    {
            "com.foo.bar.configuration"
    })
```

as suggested from Baeldung: [Guide to @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#1-spring-boot-22)

The problem is that the value **15** from application.properties is not read but instead the default value **10L** is used.

Comment: Have you added `@EnableConfigurationProperties(YourConfigProperties.class)` in your main class?

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2.2, Spring finds and registers \@ConfigurationProperties classes via classpath scanning. Therefore, there is no need to annotate such classes with \@Component (and other meta-annotations like \@Configuration), or even use the \@EnableConfigurationProperties. 
I tried it anyway without success.

Comment: How is the `XyzManagementConfig` bean being used, and how are you inspecting the values in it? Are you injecting it into another class?

Comment: Yes, I intended to auto wire it in the classes that need it.

Comment: Try creating a configuration property `com.foo.bar.data.xyzmanagement.answer=42` and a field `answer: int` in your `XyzManagementConfig` to see if the problem is *really* that Spring Boot does not recognize the configuration, or that there is something fishy in these nested classes.

Comment: This way I am not able to use @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator, am I? I think it only takes exactly ONE health indicator name but not a comma separated list. Hence, I am not able to dis-/enable the indicator!??